# redirect my domain to my facebook page (for free)

Tags: domains, redirects, facebook

Ok, it's neither *my* domain nor *my* facebook page. It's a page I made for some club and I keep it on my account using free hosting. The page is not being maintained but their facebook page is very good and alive. I would like they could redirect their domain to facebook for free, but I cannot see the way. The official register (.lv) doesn't do such redirects. The free hosting, I believe, is not interested to maintain the traffic just to redirect to FB.

But now – who ***is*** interested in redirecting to FB? Facebook itself! It could only be one setting plus some procedure to verify domain ownership.

I'm not on FB and never have been. So I don't know what settings are possible or not. However, as I cannot find anything useful by googling, may it be that FB is also not interested in such redirections? How to redirect a domain to FB **free of charge**?

Comment: Registering a domain in not free, so you are paying something already.   Most domain registrars such as GoDaddy offer redirect services that are included with the domain registration.

Comment: "The free hosting, I believe, is not interested to maintain the traffic just to redirect to FB." - I'm curious, what is stopping you from implementing a redirect at your current host, even if it is just a JavaScript redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite I wouldn't want my account banned on this hosting because I did it. Moreover, I would like they care themselves about their domain, without me – there is no point that I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to purely use DNS to forward a domain to another address. DNS just turns names into IP addresses so you would have to set this domains nameservers to somewhere which would allow you to redirect it's traffic.

Some registrars offer DNS services where you can set records or setup forwards but as you have mentioned it appears that the .lv registrar does not.

Facebook also does not offer a service in which you can set your domains nameservers to facebook to setup redirections.

If you want to remove this from your current DNS and forwarding method you will have to find a free provider who offers this as a service.

I won't suggest any services specifically but searching for "Free DNS hosting" then browsing the features of these providers to find one which offers Web Redirects will get you what you want.

All you would have to do is setup the redirect at the provider and then change the domains nameservers.